# Circles that are tangents of each other. How do I detect which circle is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, geometry

I created a `UIView` subclass that looks like this:

[image]

It is 21 circles packed in a triangular shape. The circles are tangents of each other.

I want to know which circle is touched when a tap gesture is recognised. Specifically, I want to know the row number (0 refers to the top row, 5 refers to the bottom row) and the index (0 refers to the leftmost circle) of the touched circle.

This is how I draw the circles. There's nothing wrong with this code AFAIK. I provided this code so that you can reproduce my custom `UIView`.

```
// This is the frame that I actually draw the circles in, because the view's
// bounds is not always the perfect size. This frame is supposed to be centered in the view's bounds
var actualBoardFrame: CGRect {
    if bounds.width < bounds.height {
        return CGRect(x: 0,
                      y: (bounds.height - bounds.width) / 2,
                      width: bounds.width,
                      height: bounds.width)
            .insetBy(dx: 3, dy: 3)
    } else {
        return CGRect(x: (bounds.width - bounds.height) / 2,
                      y: 0,
                      width: bounds.height,
                      height: bounds.height)
            .insetBy(dx: 3, dy: 3)
    }
}

var circleDiameter: CGFloat {
    return actualBoardFrame.height / 6
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    for row in 0..<board.rowCount {
        for index in 0...row {
            let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: pointInViewFrame(forCircleInRow: row, atIndex: index), size: size))
            path.lineWidth = 3
            UIColor.black.setStroke()
            path.stroke()
        }
    }

}

// Sorry for the short variable names. I worked this formula out on paper with maths,
// so I didn't bother to write long names
func pointInBoardFrame(forCircleInRow row: Int, atIndex index: Int) -> CGPoint {
    let n = CGFloat(board.rowCount)
    let c = CGFloat(board.rowCount - row - 1)
    let w = actualBoardFrame.width
    let h = actualBoardFrame.height
    let x = (2 * w * CGFloat(index) + w * c) / (2 * n)
    let y = (n - c - 1) * h / n + (c * (circleDiameter / 2) * tan(.pi / 8))
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

// This converts the point in the actualBoardFrame's coordinate space
// to a point in the view.bounds coordinate space
func pointInViewFrame(forCircleInRow row: Int, atIndex index: Int) -> CGPoint {
    let point = pointInBoardFrame(forCircleInRow: row, atIndex: index)
    return CGPoint(x: point.x + actualBoardFrame.origin.x, y: point.y + actualBoardFrame.origin.y)
}
```

One way I tried to detect which circle is touched is this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
    let pointInBoardFrame = CGPoint(x: point.x - actualBoardFrame.origin.x, y: point.y - actualBoardFrame.origin.y)
    guard pointInBoardFrame.y >= 0 else { return }

    // This line below makes an incorrect assumption
    let touchedRow = Int(pointInBoardFrame.y / circleDiameter)
    let rowStart = self.pointInBoardFrame(forCircleInRow: touchedRow, atIndex: 0).x
    let rowEnd = self.pointInBoardFrame(forCircleInRow: touchedRow, atIndex: touchedRow).x + circleDiameter
    guard pointInBoardFrame.x >= rowStart && pointInBoardFrame.x <= rowEnd else { return }
    let touchedIndex = Int((pointInBoardFrame.x - rowStart) / circleDiameter)


    print("touched circle: \(touchedRow) \(touchedIndex)")
}
```

The above does not work because it makes an incorrect assumption that the y coordinate of the tap can be used to unambiguously determine the row touched. This not true because there exist horizontal lines that pass through two rows.

How can I do this?

Comment: Iterate through the circles' radii, calculate the distance b/w the touch point and the center of the circle (using `hypot`, for example), and if any of those distances are less than or equal to the radius, you know you tapped on or in the circle in question.

Comment: If the individual circle are `UIBezierPath`, you can also use [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624345-contains) method (again, iterating through all the paths for all the circles).

Comment: @Rob by `hypot` do you mean the Pythagoras Theorem?

Comment: Yes, there is a `hypot` function that calculates that for you.

Comment: Do you want mathematical solution, or problem might be solved with some UI object interaction?

Comment: In main view you can add  Tap Gesture where are you drawing all the circles. Now On tap you have method  `location(in)` in gesture . So you can iterate through all circle and check any of contains it or not https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624219-location

Comment: @MBo I don’t have a preference. Whichever needs less code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both methods requires O(1) time, but the first one eats memory.

Simple solution: make hidden picture with the same circles, but draw every circle with specific color, for example: `R component = row index, G component = index in the row`. When tapping, translate coordinates to that picture and get color value in that point.

---

Math solution:

[image]

Represent tap coordinates in the basis of u-v vectors.

```
s3 = Sqrt(3)
u = (-R, R*s3)
v = (R, R*s3)
```

Every cartesian point `(x,y)` (*relative to the center of top circle, OY axis is down!*) might be represented as linear combination

```
x = a * ux + b * vx
y = a * uy + b * vy
```

We need to get a and b coefficients

```
multiply and subtract
x * uy = a * ux * uy + b * vx * uy
y * ux = a * uy * ux + b * vy * ux
x * uy - y * ux = b * (vx * uy - vy * ux)
b = (x * uy - y * ux) / (vx * uy - vy * ux)
x * vy - y * vx = a * (ux * vy - uy * vx)
a = (y * vx  - x * vy)/ (vx * uy - vy * ux)
```

Denominator is constant, so formulas are quite simple

```
denom = vx * uy - vy * ux = R * R * s3 + R * S3 * R =  2 * R^2 * s3 

a = (y * R - x * R*s3) / (2 * R^2 * s3) = - x / (2*R) + y / (2*R*s3)
b  = (x * R * s3 +  y * R ) / (2 * R^2 * s3) = x / (2*R) +  y / (2*R*s3)
```

After calculation of `a` and `b` round them to the closest integers and get row/index:

```
aa = round(a)
bb = round(b) 
row = a + b
index = b
```

Example:

```
R = 2
x = 2, y = 3.4 (near right center on my picture)
a = 0  b = 1
row = 1  index = 1

x = -2, y = 3.4  (near left center on my picture)
a = 1  b = 0 
row = 1  index = 0
```

Comment: In the diagram, the centre of the bottom circles should lie directly on the bold vertical line, right?

Comment: Yes, picture is not quite accurate - both centers and line of touch should lie on bold verticals

Comment: Is `a` the row and `b` the index?

Comment: Oh, sorry, no, they are not your rows but inclined ones. I'll formulate more exact

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate through your circles, and see what the distance between the hit point and the center is, and if less than the radius, then you know you tapped in that circle.

For example, based upon how you iterated in `draw(_:)`, you could do something like:

```
func identifyCircle(for point: CGPoint) {
    let radius = size.width / 2

    for row in 0..<board.rowCount {
        for index in 0...row {
            let origin = pointInViewFrame(forCircleInRow: row, atIndex: index)
            let center = CGPoint(x: origin.x + size.width / 2, y: origin.y + size.height / 2)
            let distance = hypot(center.x - point.x, center.y - point.y)
            if distance <= radius {
                print(Date(), "tapped in \(row), \(index)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let point = touch.location(in: self)

    identifyCircle(for: point)
}
```

Whether you use the touches methods or gesture recognizer really isn't material. But this is one way to determine which circle the `CGPoint` fell within.

Note, this assumes we're dealing with circles. If not, you'd probably want to fall back on the [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624345-contains) method of the `UIBezierPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Tag number when draw circle and use follow method to get circle tag number, So you can get which circle is tapped.

```
@objc func circleTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { //Atul added on 13 Dec 2018
        print("Tapped circle tag number is: ",(sender.view?.tag)!)
    }
```

Comment: I am not currently using subviews for the circles but I guess I could do that. Do I need a different recogniser for each of the circle views?

Comment: And even if you were using subviews, this would not be adequate. He wants to know if he tapped in the circle, not on the rectangle that encompasses the circle.

Comment: yes @Sweeper you have not used subview but can you give tag value when draw circle? if yes then you can easily get when tapped.